# Linq to object - ranking items out of 100 in descending order

Tags: linq

I have the following array of numbers:

```
Dim lst() As Integer = {4, 3, 200, 250, 670, 1, 450, 3, 10, 15, 900, 450}
```

I need to list them as a series of objects with the number and their corresponding Rank out of 100, with the results as below:

```
Number    Rank
900       100
670       90
450       80
450       80
250       60
200       50
15        40
10        30
4         20
3         10
3         10
1         0
```

I'm stumped - I've currently got this:

```
Dim t = From l In lst 
          Order By l Descending 
          Select New With {
                   .Number = l, 
                   .Rank = ((From o In lst Where o > l Select o).Distinct.Count + 1)}
```

This technique will be used on a series of lists of approximately 3000+ objects, and I suspect that the performance of my approach will be dire and could be improved when I use it with a full dataset.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not optimal, since you are enumerating the list for every item when you are setting the Rank property in the anonymous object.

A much smarter solution is to utilize the sorting to figure out the `percentile` based on the last item index.

```
var sorted = lst.OrderByDescending(n => n).ToList();

var result = sorted.Select((val) => new
{
    Number = val,
    Rank = (sorted.Count - (sorted.LastIndexOf(val) + 1)) * 100 / sorted.Count

}).ToList();
```

This is more than **10x** faster than your solution for 3,000 items.

You can easily convert my C# code to VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll test it out. It certainly looks like a better solution. If I could ask a further question, is it possible to sort the list so that Nulls appear in the middle?

Comment: Can you give an example of the sorting you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure, given a list of 50, 50, 100, Null, 90 I would like the list to come back as [Number, Rank] = [100, 100], [90,75], [Null, 50], [50, 25], [50,25]. I've coded it in normal code for now, but hopefully a linq expression will be quicker, and this is code that will run a few thousand times during an operation.

Comment: I am not sure if you expect nulls to always equal 50. If that is the case than you can just assign 50 to null values in the Rank statement above, and then re-sort. That would be the simplest i guess.

Comment: Not a great example then - it needs to be the centre rank, whatever that may be.

Comment: You could implement a custom sorting algorithm to put the nulls in the middle like { 100, 90, null, 50, 50 }, and then use that algorithm instead of the OrderByDescending extension method in my example. That would probably work ;) you will have to use nullable integers.

Comment: You can ask that as a new question (i mean implementing the sorting algorithm) :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it... I was pretty close already:

```
Dim lst() As Integer = {4, 3, 200, 250, 670, 1, 450, 15, 15, 15, 900, 450}
Dim t = (From l In lst Order By l Descending).Select(
            Function(l, Index) New With {
                 .Number = l,
                 .Rank = 100 - (((From o In lst Where o > l Select o).Count + 1) - 1) * 100 / lst.Count})
```